# Printing image view from assets manager inside form using Google Cloud Print

Tags: android, printing, webview, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to print a form with my tablet, using Google Cloud Print,
in my form there's a logo, that i want to print.
I manage to display the image view and the html text perfectly in my web view using

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
            createHtmlSnippet(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

the problem is when i'm sending the data to google cloud print,
the text is ok except for the image which is empty..

anybody knows how to send image view to google cloud print?
this is part of my code, thanks..

the line when im adding the src of the image

```
 strVar += "<img src=\"file:///android_asset/logo.png\" width=\"360px\"/>";
```

when im click on "print" button

```
          // save the file into storage
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/PrintText/";
            String mTimeStamp = null;
            try {
                mTimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

                File root = new File(mPath);
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                File gpxfile = new File(root, mTimeStamp + ".txt");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                writer.append(createHtmlSnippet());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PrintDialogActivity.class);
            i.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath + mTimeStamp + ".txt")),
                    "text/html");
            i.putExtra("title", getString(R.string.questionnare_pragnent)
                    + mTimeStamp);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```